# R bigrquery on GCP - ADC authentication Forbidden (HTTP 403)

Tags: r, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api

There is an issue where ADC authentication is not possible through the R library. Forbidden (HTTP 403)...

It seems to be a problem with the UTM whitelist.

needs to check the address to which the authentication request is sent.
Can I check which domains I need to add more UTM list?

[Forbidden (HTTP 403) image.. click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YuD7.jpg)

```
[ UTM List ]
*.googleapis.com
*.appspot.com
*.cloudfunctions.net
*.cloudproxy.app
*.cloud.google.com
*.googleusercontent.com
*.gcr.io
*.googleadapis.com
*.pkg.dev
*.run.app
*.pki.goog
*.gstatic.com
*.ltsapis.goog
*.google.com
*.github.io
*.debian.org
*.ubuntu.com
*.docker.com
*.whatap.io
*.googlecloud.com
*.github.com
*.postgresql.org
*.fastlydns.net
files.pythonhosted.org
pypi.org
pypi.python.org
cran.r-project.org
*.amazonaws.com
charts.helm.sh
charts.jenkins.io
helm.gethue.com
launchpadcontent.net
ppa.launchpadcontent.net
*.anaconda.com
*.anaconda.org
bastion-sp-apnortheast2.prod.spddevops.com
```

Comment: Please don't include images in questions. Images may not outlive the question and preclude copying-and-pasting.

Comment: It's unclear whether the library supports ADC and even if it did, you need (should) not set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to `gcloud`'s application default credentials. The [documentation](https://bigrquery.r-dbi.org/index.html#authentication-and-authorization) suggests that you should either use a user account (interactive) or can use a Service Account. For the Service Account, you will need to create a key and provide it to the [`bq_auth`](https://bigrquery.r-dbi.org/reference/bq_auth.html) in the `path` arg.

Comment: @DazWilkin When I turned off the UTM application, it was confirmed that the ADC authentication was properly authenticated as a personal account. However, we do have a policy for applying UTM.

Comment: Perhaps monitor the browser's developer tools, identify the call that's 403'ing and backtrack from there. I suspect you're **not** missing an endpoint (`*.google.com` and `*.googleapis.com` cover Google's OAuth endpoints).